# PHP SOAP SSL problems

Tags: php, soap, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a secure SOAP server using NuSOAP.  (I gave the built-in SOAP library a chance, but that was behaving strangely, so I switched to NuSOAP.)

Here's my code:

```
require('application/libraries/nusoap/nusoap.php');
$soap = new nusoap_client('https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl', 'wsdl');
$soap->setCredentials('WS'.STORE_NUMBER.'._.1',
    PASSWORD,
    'certificate',
    array(
        'sslcertfile' => 'first_data/cert.pem',
        'sslkeyfile' => 'first_data/key.pem',
        'passphrase' => KEY_PASSPHRASE
    )
);
if($err = $soap->getError()) {
    die('Error: '.$err);
}
$result = $soap->call('fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderRequest', array('v1:Transaction' => '1'));
if($soap->fault) {
    echo 'Fault! <pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    if($err = $soap->getError()) {  
        die('Error: '.$err);
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);
        die('</pre>');
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: wsdl error: Getting https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 56: SSL read: error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert decrypt error, errno 0
url: https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com:443/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl
content_type: 
http_code: 0
header_size: 0
request_size: 163
filetime: -1
ssl_verify_result: 0
redirect_count: 0
total_time: 0.531131
namelookup_time: 0.00121
connect_time: 0.070608
pretransfer_time: 0.305044
size_upload: 0
size_download: 0
speed_download: 0
speed_upload: 0
download_content_length: -1
upload_content_length: 0
starttransfer_time: 0
redirect_time: 0
```

What could be the possible problems?  How could I debug this?  I'm rather out of my league here.

Comment: Hallo ? I've tried to do the same and I've got `Error: operation fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderRequest not present in WSDL.` did you face the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error:

```
SSL read: error:1409441B:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert 
decrypt error, errno 0
```

It looks to me like the PHP library is having trouble reading your cert.pem and key.pem files.  These files can come in different formats.  Apache requires that these be in PKCS12 format and I would guess PHP is the same.  You can use a tool called "Keystore Explorer 4.0.1" to verify and convert if necessary.

You can verify the validity of the format of the keys also, using openssl and this command:

```
C:\Temp> openssl pkcs12 -info -in ksb_cert.p12
```

Comment: It is very possible I'm using the wrong file.  Here are the files I was given:

Comment: WS.key
WS.key.pw.txt
WS.ks
WS.ks.pw.txt
WS.p12
WS.p12.pw.txt
WS.pem

Comment: Could you suggest which ones would go under sslkeyfile and sslcertfile?

Comment: Oh, and, also, which of the .txt to use as the passphrase.

Comment: Well, you use either the keystore (which should have the public and private key inside of it) or use use the .key (private key) and the public key (.p12 or .pem). It depends on how your project/code is setup to read keys.  I'm not a PHP programmer and so in that context I cant answer you on that.

Answer (score 0):

With this settings my client working finally

```js
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdlurl,'wdsl');
$client->setUseCURL(true);
$client->useHTTPPersistentConnection();
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```